# Python created Word files are set to read-only when opened through Win explorer

Tags: python, file, python-3.7, readonly

I am a newbie, currently familiarizing myself with manipulating files.

I created a text file through Python 3.7 with the line:

`open(r"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Python\new.docx","w+")`

Which creates said file.

When opening a .docx file through explorer Word prompts that the file is read-only by Unknown User. Explorer file properties says it's not set to read-only. Changing the last argument doesn't change results.

How do I get the created files to be read-and-write when opened through explorer?

Comment: Word may be confused as to what that file is supposed to be – but so am I. You cannot create a .docx file by simply writing some plain text to a file. If you are set on trying to create .docx files, look for a suitable library (there are a couple). If you only want to write something in a file, use a plain text format for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem you described, try closing the file:
`open(r"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Python\new.docx","w+").close()`

If that works, you simply weren't closing the file. The `open()` built-in doesn't close the file for you; the file just stays open until you close it explicitly or close the interpreter. Using a [`with`](https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) statement is an even better idea, so you don't have to remember to close the file.

To save you some future frustration, you should know that you're not really creating a .docx file the right way. The file specification is more complicated than simply writing out with the "w" option.

To create a new empty Word file with docx (after installing the [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library, and importing `docx`), use `doc = docx.Document()`. Then use `doc.save(<new file path>)` to write the file.

python-docx obviously isn't the only library that will write a .docx file, it's just the one that I used the one time I needed to write a Word file.

Comment: I indeed was not closing the file. I tried the same with .otd files using a free Word substitude and it gave the same issue. As soon as I read your answer I realized it had to be the closing part as it's not Word specific. I'm checking out the python-docx, thanks!

Comment: If you get in the habit of using `with open(file, mode) as file:` pattern it will feel weird to use `open()` by itself and you'll never have that problem again. Glad I could help.